# convergent $f(a_n)$ for divergent $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Could you give an example of a divergent $a_n$ such that:

1) $\exp (a_n)$ is convergent

2) $a^2_n - a_n + 1$ is convergent

$a_n$ need not to be the same for two cases.

Comment: 1) $a_n=-n$, 2) $a_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: The "intended" answer for 2 may have been $a_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}2$, but in fact $a_n=\frac{1+(-1)^nc}2$ with arbitrary $c\ne0$ works.

Comment: For number 1 $a_n$ just needs to diverge to $-\infty$. I'm not sure about the second one though...

Comment: @Barry Have you tried to plot the exponential function? Then there is only one way in which $\{a_n\}$ is divergent and $\{e^{a_n}\}$ convergent.

Answer (score 3):

For 2.), consider

$$1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \dots$$